# GCP Storage - How to set custom metadata in resumable upload?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'm using the Storage JSON api.

Edit to be more specific:

When I :

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/myBucket/o?uploadType=resumable HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer [MY_AUTH_TOKEN]
Content-Length: 38
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Upload-Content-Type: image/jpeg
X-Upload-Content-Length: 2000000

{ "name": "myObject", "foo":  "bar" }
```

Then only the name of the file is set and I'd like to see `"foo" : "bar"` in the `metadata` fields.

---

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload):

(1)

> The /upload URI, for the media. The format of the /upload endpoint is
>   the standard resource URI with an /upload prefix. Use this URI when
>   transferring the media data itself. Example: POST
>   /upload/storage/v1/b/myBucket/o.

And

(2)

> The standard resource URI, for the metadata. If the resource contains
>   any data fields, those fields are used to store metadata describing
>   the uploaded file. You can use this URI when creating or updating
>   metadata values. Example: POST /storage/v1/b/myBucket/o.

They also say as an example of an `/upload` (1) request :

> If you have metadata for the file, add the metadata to the request
>   body in JSON format. Otherwise, leave the request body empty.

Those contradict a bit.

Nonetheless, sending a json body to an `/upload` : only setting the 'name' attribute works.

Sending the same json body to a metadata request gets me a  :

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "wrongUrlForUpload",
    "message": "Upload requests must include an uploadType URL parameter and a URL path beginning with /upload/",
...
```

Thanks ! :)

EDIT: this is mainly to assign that file to whoever it belongs to and also verify hashes, I can totally work around this with the `name` of the image.

Comment: Unless you are modifying only metadata, use the /upload endpoint with uploadType=resumable - the examples in the documentation show how to do this.  Can you be more specific in your question about the request/response that are not working for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set custom metadata on your object upload via the JSON API, use this kind of message body:

`{"name": "myObject", "metadata": {"foo": "bar"}}`

Comment: Awesome ! Thank you so much :)